# jquery issue if checked change bg color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i made a script that is supposed to change background when radio is selected. It works but when another radio is selected the previous still remains with the selected color. It works for checkboxes but not for radio.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".table").change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? "#18b9e7" : "#b6bf34";
  $(this).parent().css("background-color", c);
});
</script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvP3f/9/)

Comment: in the fiddle you are using checkboxes not radios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this:

Your fiddle contains checkboxes instead radio buttons, make sure it's radios or checkboxes.

```
$('.table').change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? '#00B0EA' : '#B6BF34';
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#00B0EA').siblings().css('background-color', '');
});
```

- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UvP3f/18/)

Comment: you can rewrite this to have var $parent = $(this).parent() not to check twice

Comment: Hey, thnx it's working, i'm new to jquery didnt know about siblings. It's working perfect. Thnx

Comment: @RobertMesserle That's better too!

Answer (score 0):

add a

```
$(ALL RADIOS SELECTOR).css('background-color', DISABLED_COLOR)
```

before the change for example

```
$(".table").change(function() {

  var $this = $(this),
      c     = this.checked ? "#18b9e7" : "#b6bf34"

  $this.find('input[type="checkbox"]').parent().css('background-color', "#b6bf34");

  $this.parent().css("background-color", c);

});
```

change checkbox to radio if necessary

Answer (score 0):

This is simplier:

```
$(".table").change(function(){

  $(".table").parent()                     //all the inputs
      .css("background-color", "#b6bf34"); //to be green

  $("input[name=masa]:checked").parent()   //only the checked
      .css("background-color", "#00B0EA"); //to be blue
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UvP3f/12/

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/UvP3f/10/

```
var $labels = $(".m1");
$('.table').change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? '#00B0EA' : '#B6BF34';
  $labels.removeAttr("style");
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', c);
});
```

Cache the reference to your `$labels` outside of the `change` handler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the radio buttons are that once you change the value of one automatically deselects the other ones but just trigger the change event on the clicked control, you need to check for all controls and apply the same logic everytime the change event are triggered:

```
$('.table').change(function(){
    $('.table').each(function(){
        var c = this.checked ? '#00B0EA' : '#B6BF34';
          $(this).parent().css('background-color', c);
    });
});
```